# multiple htaccess file complication

Tags: .htaccess, magento

i have a magento webshop which has following rule in his base .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Now i have a subdirectory in the webshop root called "oscware". In this folder is also a htaccess file with following content:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter your ID and password"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user
```

if i want to connect to http://www.example.com/oscware/oscware-connector.php i will be redirected to the magento shop with error 404.

If i remove the rule

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

it works. Ok everybody should think that the problem is in the rewrite condition. But it is NOT so. Because at the other side if i remove the rule

```
require valid-user
```

in the .htaccess file in the oscware directory it also works (with the rule

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

)

At the end i can only edit the magento .htaccess in the webshop-root because the oscware .htaccess is automatically generated. Has anybody an idea to get this scenario working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have solved the problem with following statement in the .htaccess-file:
    ErrorDocument 401 test.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is happening. The only thing that I can think of is maybe an internal 401 page is missing and that's somehow causing the rule in the document root to get applied. Unless there's other rules or redirects in the "oscware" or magento that is inadvertently causing this.

But try, in the htaccess file in your "oscware" folder, turn on the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On
```